# Granting Privilege on SCHEMA

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have two SCHEMA in a database(ABC,XYZ)

Now i want to create a user Test and grant select privilege only on SCHEMA (XYZ)

I know how to grant Privilege to a user, but confused how to grant privilege on specific SCHEMA?

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible, the database does not support such grants.
You can grant the required privileges on each object individually in the schema.

For example:

```
begin
  for o in (select * from dba_tables where owner = 'XYZ')
  loop
    execute immediate 'grant read on "' || o.owner || '"."' || o.table_name || '" to ABC';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

It is better to create a role, grant that role to the other user, and maintain the grants to the role when you create new objects.

[image]

*grant_system_privileges::=*

[image]

*grant_object_privileges::=*

[image]

*on_object_clause ::=*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all create the user

```
CREATE USER Test IDENTIFIED BY "123456";
```

Grant the user the basic privilege to connect to the database

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Test;
```

---

Now you can specify which tables you want to grant the privilege on

```
GRANT SELECT ON Test.TableName to XYZ;
```

---

You can also grant the user privileges on different objects under XYZ

```
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT object_name, object_type FROM all_objects WHERE owner='XYZ' AND object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW','PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE')) LOOP
    IF t.object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW') THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON XYZ.'||t.object_name||' TO Test';
    ELSIF t.object_type IN ('PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE') THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT EXECUTE ON XYZ.'||t.object_name||' TO Test';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;

/
```

Comment: Nevermind, but the pl/sql I have in my answer has more capabilities in terms of granting select update delete to tables and view, besides granting execute to procedures, functions and packages.

It is not limited to just grant select on tables only